# Setting Visual Studio Project Dependencies from CMake

Tags: dll, dependencies, cmake

I'm using CMake to build an application made up of four projects:

- *a.dll*, which has no dependency
- *b.dll*, which depends on *a.dll*
- *c.exe*, which depends on *a.dll* and *b.dll*
- *d.exe*, which depends on *a.dll* and *b.dll*

Each project (or target in CMake's terminology) lies in its own subdirectory, and has its own *CMakeLists.txt* file. In addition there's a top-level *CMakeLists.txt* file that binds them all (using `add_subdirectory`).

In the *CMakeLists.txt* files of *b.dll*, *c.exe* and *d.exe*, I'm using `target_link_libraries` to link these targets to the import libraries of *a.dll* and *b.dll*. That works properly. So far, so good.

Now, in Visual Studio, it appears that CMake doesn't set any "Project Dependencies" between the various projects of the solution: if I go to *Project -> Project Dependencies...*, I can see that indeed *b.dll* doesn't have a dependency to *a.dll*, *c.exe* doesn't have a dependency to neither *a.dll* nor *b.dll*, etc. The result is that the build order of the projects is essentially random, and in practice the solution simply fails to build (because, for instance, *c.exe* is built before *a.dll*, and thus the corresponding import library *a.lib* has not yet been generated).

I'm rather puzzled.  I've been scouting the net for an answer very thoroughly, but without luck (which makes me think this is a non-issue for most CMake users, and I must be doing something wrong).

Note that I also tried to use the `add_dependencies` command, but that had no effect.

I'm using CMake 2.8.1 and Visual Studio 2008 (9.0).

Thanks,
Franz

---

Here are the *CMakeLists.txt* files, for reference:

top-level *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_subdirectory(a)
add_subdirectory(b)
add_subdirectory(c)
add_subdirectory(d)
```

*a/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_library(a SHARED a.cpp)
```

*b/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_library(b SHARED b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(b a)
# also tried to add add_dependencies(b a) here
```

*c/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(c c.cpp)
target_link_libraries(c a b)
# also tried to add add_dependencies(c a b) here
```

*d/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(d d.cpp)
target_link_libraries(d a b)
# also tried to add add_dependencies(d a b) here
```

Comment: target_link_libraries is the correct command. Can you confirm you are using the library / executable name instead of the name of the project.

Comment: The setup I described in my question is actually correct, and it indeed works as expected.  It looks like my problem was due to cache pollution/desynchronization after a lot of tweaking of my *CMakeLists.txt* files (in particular, I have the feeling that moving the `project` command from one *CMakeLists.txt* file to the one in the parent directory messed up the cache quite a bit...). Thanks for the comment, in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup described in my question is correct and works as expected.  See my comment above.